# Why is this C code giving me a seg fault?

Tags: c, string, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy char *str to char c[] in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508838/how-to-copy-char-str-to-char-c-in-c)

```
char *token = "some random string";
char c[80];  
strncpy(c, token, sizeof c - 1); 
c[79] = '\0';
char *broken = strtok(c, "#");
```

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508838/how-to-copy-char-str-to-char-c-in-c

Comment: But a different question. I am asking for the exact coding problem. That's what SO is about.

Comment: What are you trying to do with lines 3-5, with the two copies and the setting of the last char as \0?  If you insert some helpful printfs, do you know how far you make it before it dies?

Comment: See answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508838/how-to-copy-char-str-to-char-c-in-c/1508875#1508875

Comment: @Alex Xander - how is it a different question? The code is exactly the same, and your question (why does it seg fault) is the same.

Comment: just copied in a file and compiled it. It works flawlessy (gcc 4.3.3). I just added the includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not crash for me in the following:

```
#include <string.h>

main()
{
char *token = "some random string";
char c[80];  
strcpy( c, token);
strncpy(c, token, sizeof c - 1); 
c[79] = '\0';
char *broken = strtok(c, "#");
}
```

Comment: he doesn't use: strcpy( c, token);
Perhaps you could be clearer why this extra step is critical?

Comment: @Egwor, in the earlier revisions it was the same. I suppose that is what was causing the problem in cases where token pointed to a string which was too long.

Answer (score 0):

This code works, have you specified the correct includes?

```
#include <string.h> /*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main() {
  /* ORIGINAL CODE */
  char *token = "some random string";
  char c[80];  
  strcpy( c, token);
  strncpy(c, token, sizeof c - 1); 
  c[79] = '\0';
  char *broken = strtok(c, "#");

  /* ADDED THE FOLLOWING LINES */
  printf("%s\n", broken);
  exit(1);
}
```